# How to increase slider track width in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

In `SliderThemeData` `trackheight` is given but I want to increase the track's width.

Here is my current code:

```
SliderTheme(
    data: SliderThemeData(
      trackHeight: 1,
    ),
    child: RangeSlider(
      min: 0.0, 
      max: 4.0,
      onChanged: _onChange,
      values: state.value,
      onChangeEnd: _onChangeEnd,
      inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
      activeColor: Theme.of(state.context).accentColor,
    ),
),
```

Comment: could you add UI or image.?

Comment: Image ui added pls see the link above

Comment: can't see image or url.

Comment: try to put the slider as child of Expanded

Answer (score 15):

You can use SliderTheme to customize the slider appearance and wrap Slider with Container to give custom width for the slider. It will take Container width as Slider width.

```
  SliderTheme(
            data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
              activeTrackColor: Colors.blue,
              inactiveTrackColor: Colors.blue,
              trackShape: RectangularSliderTrackShape(),
              trackHeight: 4.0,
              thumbColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 12.0),
              overlayColor: Colors.red.withAlpha(32),
              overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 28.0),
            ),
            child: Container(
              width: 400,
              child: Slider(
                min: 0,
                max: 1000,
                divisions: 5,
                value: _currentFontSize,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentFontSize = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 12):

This simplified solution worked for me:

```
 SliderTheme(
    data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
       overlayShape: SliderComponentShape.noOverlay,
    ),
    child: Slider(),
 )
```

Comment: Straight to the point, thanks.

Comment: Tested it and it looks like a good solution.  u got yourself a point

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your question correctly, I think what you're referring to is the inherent padding on the left and right of the Slider widget itself.

This is down to the slider track needing space at either end of the track for the thumb and overlay.

You can override this using a with a custom [RoundedRectSliderTrackShape](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RoundedRectSliderTrackShape-class.html) and adding it to the `trackShape:` argument in the [SliderThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData-class.html).

An example on how to do this is [described here on the Flutter issues page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37057#issuecomment-518162602) by @clocksmith. Basically, the code example is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SliderTheme(
          data: SliderThemeData(
            trackShape: CustomTrackShape(),
          ),
          child: Slider(
            value: _value,
            onChanged: (double value) {
              setState(() {
                _value = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTrackShape extends RoundedRectSliderTrackShape {
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    @required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    @required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
  }) {
    final double trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight;
    final double trackLeft = offset.dx;
    final double trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight) / 2;
    final double trackWidth = parentBox.size.width;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }
}
```

Obviously, I take no credit for this. I was looking for a similar solution, when I came across this answer on the Flutter issues page. All credit to the original author!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to full width of parent.
Wrap with Expanded.

```
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Slider(
                  value: 10,
                  onChanged: (val) {},
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `Slider` with `SliderThemeData` and change `trackHeight`

```
SliderThemeData(
        trackHeight: 2, // change height here
     ),
      child: Slider(),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

`RangeSlider` changes its width according to its parent width, so wrap the `RangeSlider` with the container and give the container `width` property.

```
Container(
  width: 300,
  child: RangeSlider(
     min: 0.0,
     max: 4.0,
     onChanged: _onChange,
     values: state.value,
     onChangeEnd: _onChangeEnd,
     inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
     activeColor: Theme.of(state.context).accentColor,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fit the width of the Slider into app screen width then
Wrap Slider with SliderTheme And  set overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 0.0) to get maximum width of slider